# How to catch "Connection closed while receiving data" from http.send in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement a reconnect logic to the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_client_sse package. The http connection stays open and listens to server side events. When the connection is lost for some reason the client should try to reconnect.
An exception is thrown as soon as the connection is lost but I'm not able to catch it.

Code for building the connection:

```
     try {
        _client = http.Client();
        var request = http.Request("GET", Uri.parse(url));
        //Adding headers to the request
        request.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
        request.headers["Accept"] = "text/event-stream";

        Future<http.StreamedResponse> response = _client.send(request);
        response.onError((e, s) {
          Log.e("ERROR!");
          throw e.cause ?? e;
        });
        response.catchError((e) => Log.e("ERROR!"));
        response.asStream().listen((data) {
         ... 
        });
     } catch(e) {
         Log.e("ERROR!");
     }
```

When the connection is lost an exception is thrown:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Connection closed while receiving data
E/flutter (24389): #0      IOClient.send.<anonymous closure> (package:http/src/io_client.dart:49:13)
E/flutter (24389): #1      _invokeErrorHandler (dart:async/async_error.dart:45:24)
E/flutter (24389): #2      _HandleErrorStream._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:272:9)
E/flutter (24389): #3      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
E/flutter (24389): #4      _HttpClientResponse.listen.<anonymous closure> (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:712:16)
E/flutter (24389): #5      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1378:47)
E/flutter (24389): #6      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1272:19)
E/flutter (24389): #7      _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1178:7)
```

How can I catch this excption to do the reconnect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the response in `try` `catch` blocks to catch http errors,
I modified your code a little

First `try` block

```
    try {
    _client = http.Client();
    var request = http.Request("GET", Uri.parse(url));
    //Adding headers to the request
    request.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
    request.headers["Accept"] = "text/event-stream";

    // wait for the response
    http.StreamedResponse response =await _client.send(request);

    // then listen to the stream
    response.stream.listen((data) {}, onError: (e, s) {});
    }
```

Second `catch` block

you need to check the the error type on `catch` block, in your case it's `ClientException`

```
catch (e) {
    if (e is ClientException) {
      // handel error
    }
  }
```

Then you can check the error message

```
if (e is ClientException) {
  if (e.message == 'Connection closed while receiving data') {
    // handel error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 7mada for the response. This is my implementation with his solution:

```
  Future<void> connect(String path) async {
    try {
      final _client = http.Client();

      final request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(baseUrl + path));

      final response = await _client.send(request);

      response.stream.listen(
        (data) {
          _streamController.add(utf8.decode(data));
        },
        onError: (e, s) {
          if (e is http.ClientException) {
            connect(path);
          }
        },
      );
    } on Exception catch (_) {
      // What errors could happen here?
    }
  }
```